# How to make WP sidebar responsive and display at the bottom of page on small screens?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, sidebar

I've found the following CSS code that I pasted in the child theme's css stylesheet, but it doesn't work.

```
/* Mobiles in Potrait mode */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
    .widget-area {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        background: #E3E3E3;
    }
}

/* Mobiles in landscape mode */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {
    .widget-area {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            background: #E3E3E3;
    }
}
```

You can check my [WP website](https://mexon.ca/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.widget-area` by default is contained in `.sidebar-container` so you are targetting the wrong class.

You can read more [WP-Beginners](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-styles-to-wordpress-widgets/) and [WP-Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars)

#### Update:

Based on the HTML of your website you will need:

```
.right-sidebar .content-area {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.right-sidebar .widget-area {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #E3E3E3;
}
```

The styles you added were overwritten by the `body` class `.right-sidebar`

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such class in my storefront theme. You can inspect my website at https://mexon.ca and see that .widget-area should work. Thank you for your help

Comment: It worked, thank you. I copied a copy of these two blocks of code below each of my mobile portrait and landscape modes blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

Add these codes into this file: `/wp-content/themes/storefront-child-theme-master/style.css`

```
@media (max-width: 66.4989378333em){
.col-full {
    margin-left: 2.617924em;
    margin-right: 2.617924em;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
}

@media (max-width: 66.4989378333em){
.right-sidebar .widget-area {
    width: 100%
}
}

@media (max-width: 66.4989378333em){
.right-sidebar .content-area {
    width: 100%
}
}
```